# Parametrize plane to calculate contour integrals and prove stoke’s theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

There is a vector field $G=\langle -zy^2/2, -xz^2/2, yx^2/2\rangle$ and a given plane $z=1-x-y$. I was given the curled vector field to use stokes theorem to calculate the surface integral. Basically now I have to use parametrization to deconstruct the plane and use the non curled vector field to calculate the contour integral and verify the answer which should be $1/2$. I’m not sure how to do this. Could I get some guidance please?

Comment: What is the "curved" vector field? What is the "non curved" vector field?

Comment: When a vector is “curved” it means the cross product between it and the partial derivatives is applied, ie stokes theorem.

Comment: And, haha, it’s actually called “curled”. Sorry

Comment: Check your statement again. The surface can't be the whole plane $z=1-x-y$.
BTW, what do you mean with "deconstruct" the plane??

Comment: Excuse me, it’s bound by the zy and zx planes. By deconstruct, I mean define it as the 3 different vectors, rotating counterclockwise about the triangle. The vectors would be <-1,1,0>, <0,-1,1> and <-1,0,1>

Comment: ... and $xy$ plane. Please make a try and show your work.

Comment: Sorry. I’m tired after a 10 hr shift haha. I just don’t know how to parametrize the vectors and afterwards how to convert them to that integral with respect to dr form, and afterwards if I am just to add up the calculations for each of the 3 vectors. I’d really appreciate a bit of assistance

Comment: Take your time and then read carefully this similar problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479804/verifying-stokes-theorem-on-vector-calculus?noredirect=1
I can't give you more assistance if you don't show your efforts. It is against the code of conduct of this site.